# How can I log a user in without password in django?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am trying to log a user in and I currently only know the user's email but I know for a fact that it's the correct user. The user has created a password and this is not a log in page.

So the question is how do I log the user in without the password.

I currently log people in using this:

```
user = authenticate(email=email,password=password)
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
else:
    #do something
```

but I want to do something like this:

```
user = authenticate(email=email)
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
else:
    #do something
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) takes a `User` object, you do not have to call `authenticate` to retrieve the user if you really don't want to validate the user

```
user = User.objects.get(email=email)
login(request, user)
```